# Single key for dwi or dei in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

Is there a single key for doing `dwi` or `dei` (Substitute a word) in Vi(m)? I use this enough to warrant saving 2 extra keystrokes.

Comment: `cw`? Although I usually use `ciw` to change the whole word, not just the ending. There is no single key for it, but you can `:map` it if you wish.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks! That is what I needed. Could you add it as an answer, so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `vimtutor`
2. Learn about `c`. There isn't a single key. `c`[motion] is the same as `d`[motion]`i`.

Comment: For the `vimtutor`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want a single key for that. Yeah I am serious. That's not how Vim works. Vim is modular. You first think about what you want to do, in your case you want to `c`hange something. Then you need to know what you want to `c`hange, in your case a `w`ord. And voila! `cw` is the sequence to use.

Of course there is but more to think of. Do you need a `w`ord or a `W`ORD? Do you want to change `a`round the word (`caw`)? And so on.

But the important part is, Vim is not a collection of functions, it is a language to modify text. It is always a chain of actions. Sure you could say, `ciw` is so common it should have a shortcut, then you can map it. But it will only make Vim harder to use.

Thinking about changing a whole `s`entence? Yeah, it is `cs`. The same goes for `d`eleting, or `y`anking and nearly everything else.

So if you map everything you need often to a single command, instead of a chain of commands like in vanilla Vim, you lose everything which makes Vim better than any other editor and you will end up with a worse Emacs...

Comment: I understand. I mis-constructed the question maybe because of a brainfart. 
Two keys are still good enough for me. Just needed a better semantic substitute for `d*i`. Leaving the question un-edited though, because it might help someone who googles.